# Motivational but Not - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Maybe one word, or maybe two,
Read these lines, find the clues.
Determination must first start,
Sometimes it leads to starting art.
No matter where it goes, one must first try,
Without the start of all effort, we can't fly.
The beginning of the beginning is the best,
To plan to acheive, or start another test.
Make sure when planning to end with thoughts,
Examine, begin and end to connect the dots.
So riddle it out, don't hold back.
Tell what I am, don't queue on a stack.

Comment: I think the queue on a stack made it a little obvious :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> DATABASE.

*Maybe one word, or maybe two,*

> Database or data base?

*Read these lines, find the clues.*

> It's another letterplay riddle! Aggie, I'm getting too used to your style ;-)

*Determination must first start,*

> The first letter of "determination" is **D**.

*Sometimes it leads to starting art.*

> The first letter of "art" is **A**.

*No matter where it goes, one must first try,*

> The first letter of "try" is **T**.

*Without the start of all effort, we can't fly.*

> The first letter of "all effort" is **A**.

*The beginning of the beginning is the best,*

> The first letter of "beginning" is **B**.

*To plan to acheive, or start another test.*

> The first letter of "another test" is **A**.

*Make sure when planning to end with thoughts,*

> The last letter of "thoughts" is **S**.

*Examine, begin and end to connect the dots.*

> The first and last letter of "examine" are both **E**.

*So riddle it out, don't hold back.

 Tell what I am, don't queue on a stack.*

> No queue of answers on *Stack* Exchange for this one: I got the answer as soon as I looked at it!

Comment: I think you got it!

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to have to mix things up a little more :-P. Nicely done.

Comment: I didn't pick up on all the letter hints, but the last line and then re-reading from the top made me guess that you were describing a todo list